# How to force a boolean variable equal to zero in cplex

Tags: boolean, cplex

I have a Q[b][j] variable it decides how many jobs must attend to batch 1 for example
if it attends 1 or more job to batch 1 Y[b][j] must be 1.Y[b][j] is boolean.
i tried this
forall (n in J,p in B) Q[p][n]- 9999*Y[p][n]<=0;
but i think this is not gonna work because when Q[b][j] equals to 0, Y[b][j] doesnt have to be 0.Cplex can assign 1 to Y[b][j].

How can i force  Y[b][j] value to 0 when Q[b][j] is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical constraints:

```
forall (n in J,p in B)
  Y[n][p] == (Q[n][p]>=1);
```